# Login to Azure with PAT

Tags: command-line-interface

I'm trying to login to Azure with a PAT.

After the token is input, it just prompts, leaving me thinking it went alright, but if I try an az command, it fails.

```
$ az devops login --organization https://foo.visualstudio.com
Token:
$ az account show
Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

I've also tried to pipe the environment variable into the command, but it just prompts

```
echo $AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT | az devops login --organization https://foo.visualstudio.com
```

I'm on NixOS using bash.

Any debug option to this az command or anything other I can try?

Comment: you are trying to authenticate to Azure DevOps with a Personal Access Token (PAT) and then running `az account show` which is an Azure CLI command, not an Azure DevOps command. Since you have authenticated with Azure DevOps, the Azure CLI will not recognize the authentication and will prompt you to run `az login`. Regarding the issue with piping the environment variable, it might be caused by the `az devops login` command not reading the token from stdin. You can try using the `--token` parameter directly to pass the token.

Comment: Doesn't seem to accept that: unrecognized arguments: --token

Comment: Anyways, it seems az devops commands work, so I guess I must try to understand how I can login to az. How many different places I need to login. I can't login to all of them?;)

Comment: it doesn't seem as if the "az login" command accepts any token, at all. It's just not supported to login with "az login" using a token. Is that correct?